# what to put @return when not sure JSdocs

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Hello I have a function which returns the result of a function inside that function. So I'm kind of unsure at what to put in my `@return`. I'm getting into JSdocs and this is a question I've stumbled up on.

Here's the code :

```
/**
 * @param           {string} id
 * @param           {Array} data
 * @returns         ??
 * @description     Takes in an ID to find the processor it needs and the data it needs to pass to the processor.
 */

processData(id, data) {
    let res = Object.values(methods).find(entry => entry.id === id).dataProcessor;
    if (res !== undefined) return res(data);
    console.error(`There is no method that belongs to id:${id}`)
}
```

Since it returns the results of `res.data(data)` what would you put in the @return in the docs.

Comment: it's up to you to decide, if it's a complex type that you have it, just mention its name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically I'd return an `{Object}`, or an ALL `{*}`, or even an ANY `{?}` in this situation.

https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Types-in-the-Closure-Type-System